# If a point charge is surrounded by an spherical insulator then according to the below diagram what will be the electric field at point A and point B

Tags: electric-fields, charge, insulators

[image]

According to my observations, electric field strength depends on the relative permittivity of the medium. Different insulating materials can affect the overall strength of the electric field. If is it so, then there has to be a difference in the electric field inside and outside the sphere mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply Gauss you will find that the field strengths would the same as if the insulating material was not there as the net charge within a Gaussian surface will be the magnitude of the charge at the centre.

Within the insulator the electric field is radial but reduced by a factor equal to the relative permittivity of the insulator.

Comment: That is what I'm asking, in the absence of an insulator electric field will not change but my question is different, I want to know the change in electric field in the presence of an insulator.

Comment: @AnkitKumarVishwakarma I have added to my answer.

Comment: And what if we place a spherical conductor instead of insulator, still an electric field will exist outside the sphere?

Comment: And the electric field inside the conductor would be zero.

Comment: I'm asking outside the conductor, at point B by considering the above diagram.

Comment: No change at $A$ and $B$ if the insulator is replaced by a conductor.  There may be induced charges on both a conductor and an insulator but the net charge on them is zero and so when applying Gauss only the charge at the centre needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Farcher's answer.
I would like to add analytic solution to compensate @Farcher's description.
In the followings, $\phi$ is electric scalar potential, $E_r(r)$ is electric field
and $D_r(r)$ is eletric flux density. $\epsilon_r$ is relative permitivity of dielectric
material. $R_1$ and $R_2$ are radii of spherical insulator.

$$
\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0}{Q}\phi(r) =
\begin{cases}
r^{-1} & (\text{for }0<r<R_1) \\
\epsilon_r^{-1} r^{-1} + R_1^{-1}\left(1-\epsilon_r^{-1}\right) & (\text{for }R_1 \leq r < R_2 ) \\
r^{-1}-R_2^{-1} + \epsilon_r^{-1} R_2^{-1}+ R_1^{-1}\left(1-\epsilon_r^{-1}\right) & (\text{for }R_2 \leq r)
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0}{Q}E_r(r) = \frac{4\pi\epsilon_0}{Q}\left(-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \right)=
\begin{cases}
r^{-2} & (\text{for }0<r< R_1) \\
\epsilon_r^{-1} r^{-2}& (\text{for }R_1 \leq r < R_2 ) \\
r^{-2} & (\text{for }R_2 \leq r)
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0}{Q}D_r(r) =
\begin{cases}
r^{-2} & (\text{for }0<r<R_1) \\
\epsilon_r\left(\epsilon_r^{-1} r^{-2}\right)  =r^{-2} & (\text{for }R_1 \leq r < R_2 ) \\
r^{-2} & (\text{for }R_2 \leq r)
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\text{div}\vec{D}=
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2D_r(r)\right) =
\begin{cases}
0 & (\text{for }0<r<R_1) \\
0 & (\text{for }R_1 \leq r < R_2 ) \\
0 & (\text{for }R_2 \leq r)
\end{cases}
$$